# Corda Azure Single Ledger Resource - No Cordapp in the web server issue

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am new to Corda. I am trying to follow  https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V2.0/azure-vm.html?highlight=azure to create corda single ledger setup in Azure.

As mentioned in the link, I have copied the .jar file to /opt/corda/plugins
 folder. But still  I am not able to view the Yo cordapp application. I am getting "No installed custom CorDapps." message.

corda runtime version is 2.0

Any suggestion on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you restarted the node after copying over the CorDapp JAR file? Nodes do not "hot-load" CorDapps as of Corda 3.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same. Copied cordapp jar file to /opt/corda/plugins and restarted corda and corda-webserver.

[INFO ] 2019-08-11T14:35:36,768Z [main] internal.Node.registerWithNetworkMapIfConfigured - Node successfully loaded network map data from the database.

[INFO ] 2019-08-11T14:35:36,778Z [main] messaging.NodeMessagingClient.invoke - Network map is complete, so removing filter from P2P consumer.

[INFO ] 2019-08-11T14:35:36,920Z [main] BasicInfo.printBasicNodeInfo - Providing network services              :

[INFO ] 2019-08-11T14:35:36,925Z [main] BasicInfo.printBasicNodeInfo - Loaded CorDapps                         : yo-4, corda-finance-1.0.0, corda-core-1.0.0

Application seems to have loaded.

Comment: Am getting the below error when trying to send yo! as per the step on documentation.

http://(public IP address):(port)/api/yo/yo?target=(legalname of target node)


Target string doesn't match any nodes on the network.

Am getting the target name from node.conf in Node 1 which is O=Organisation 1 (Corda 1.0.0), L=London, C=GB.

And am invoking the below URL -

http://<public_ip>:10004/api/yo/yo?target="C=GB,L=London,O=Organisation 1 (Corda 1.0.0)"

Comment: This error happens due to mismatch in node name. The node names in node.conf and in the url does not match due missing spaces in the url part. Please check.

Comment: http://<node_0_IP>:10004/api/yo/peers gives me the below nodes - 

{
  "peers" : [ "C=GB,L=London,O=Organisation 0 (Corda 1.0.0)", "C=GB,L=London,O=Network Map (Corda 1.0.0)", "C=GB,L=London,O=Organisation 1 (Corda 1.0.0)", "C=GB,L=London,O=Notary (Corda 1.0.0)" ]
}

http://<noe1_IP>:10004/api/yo/me gives - 

{
  "me" : "C=GB,L=London,O=Organisation 0 (Corda 1.0.0)"
}

With that I tried to hit this URL - 

http://<noe1_IP>:10004/api/yo/yo?target=C=GB,L=London,O=Organisation 1 (Corda 1.0.0)
But this give me the below error -
Target string doesn't match any nodes on the network.

Comment: There could be a possible disparity between the identity service and network map cache data. Please refer [link](https://r3-cev.atlassian.net/browse/CORDA-813?workflowName=Corda%20Software%20Development&stepId=4). Are you using Corda 1.0? It is recommended to use the latest version (most likely Corda version 4.0+).